# How to fill dataset with 2 datatable objects?

Tags: xml

I have a an XML file which I am loading into a dataset, I need this datatset to return 2 data tables. 
How can I achieve this? Thanks and appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a dataset having two tables, export it to xml.  Then you will have the correctly formatted XML.

Comment: Hi Steve..Thanks for the reply...But I want it the other way

Comment: I understand that.  I'm suggesting starting from the goal and working backwards.